# Volumes with space-dependent light intensity

Tags: scripting, light, volumetrics

I would like to use Blender to render pictures of atomic orbitals like in the following picture

[image]

or like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ot_g8AM-tsk&feature=youtu.be&t=204). This seems to need some light-emitting volume whose intensity is described by some formulas.

Which would be the smartest approach for this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an ***Emission*** **shader** for the *Volume* socket of your *Material output* node, and give it a volumetric texture.

It's pretty easy for a *1s* orbital, (n,l,m) = (1,0,0). (spherical symmetry, monotonic decay: it's not actually exponential in my example below):

[image]

Create a sphere, and assign a material to it like the one in the picture.

- The first three nodes to the left (*Geometry, Object Info* and *Vector Math>Subtract*) will output a vector (*x-x₀*, *y-y₀*, *z-z₀*) for each *x,y,z* point in the sphere's volume, where *x₀*,*y₀*,*z₀* is the pivot point of the sphere. The following node *Vector Mapping* can be used to scale the texture. These are **the cartesian coordinates that will be used to define a scalar function**, like a wavefunction.
- The last four nodes to the right ("*Math>Absolute*, *Color Ramp*, *Emission*, *Material output*) will **take the output of your scalar function and assign it to the volumetric emission, colored according to a color map** (I've taken the absolute value, you might want to take the 2nd power, or to have different colors for the positive and negative values).
- In the middle, you will need **your actual scalar function**. It can be any node, or group of nodes, that takes a *Vector* (blue socket) as input, and outputs a *scalar* (grey socket). In my example, I've used a *Gradient texture* node. Unfortunately, complex functions are not built-in in blender. You can, however, create a ***Script*** **node** that implements the wavefunctions (you will probably need `numpy.polynomial.legendre`)*

* I've never done this before, so I can't guarantee it's possible to just make python do the math. If it's possible, I think [this wiki page](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Phonybone/Python_Nodes#Basic_API_functions) is a good starting point.

Comment: I have little experience in creating custom nodes in Blender, so I haven't given details on that. I can't seem to find much about the Node class (I don't want to create an OSL node, just a python node). If I have some spare time later, I'll try to integrate that part of the answer.

Comment: Excellent, this is just what I needed! Thank you very much

Comment: Here you may see a finished example http://tungsteno.io/post/vis-hydrogen_wavefunction_111/ together with the script generating this video https://github.com/TungstenHub/tngt-blender/blob/master/scripts/orb11.py Thanks again!!